# IDataView for Keras Converted ONNX model for ImageClassification

Tags: c#, tensorflow, keras, ml.net, onnx

I have a Trained Model with Keras and Tensorflow Backend (Keras 2.2.4 Tensorflow 1.13.1) and i want to use that Model in Visual Studio with ML.Net.

Therefore i converted my Model to ONNX with winmltools.convert_keras (I tired it with a Tensorflow 2.0 model but i got the `No module named 'tensorflow.tools.graph_transforms'`  error).
Now i finaly managed to load the model with:

```
string outName = "dense_6";
string inName = "conv2d_9_input";
string imgFolder = "path\to\Testimage
string pathToMLFile = "path\to\.onnx"

 var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(outputColumnName: outName, imageFolder: imgFolder, inputColumnName: inName)
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outName, 299, 299, inName))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: outName, interleavePixelColors: true, offsetImage: 117))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(outputColumnName: outName, inputColumnName: inName, modelFile: pathToMLFile, fallbackToCpu: true));
```

But now i need a IDataView to "Fit" the model (from my understanding it is needed to Initialize it?)
Therefore i load an empty IDataView with:

```
var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new List<ImageNetData>());
```

with **ImageNetData** being

```
    public class ImageNetData
    {
        [ColumnName("conv2d_9_input")]
        [ImageType(299, 299)]
        public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

        [ColumnName("dense_6")]
        public string Label;
    }
```

now i get the error:

```
Schema mismatch for input column 'conv2d_9_input': expected String, got Image<299, 299>
Parametername: inputSchema
```

My model with Netron:

[image: Netron Model]

Why does it want a String? And if i remove the **[ImageType(299,299)]** and change the **Bitmap** to **string** i get:

```
Schema mismatch for input column 'conv2d_9_input': expected Image, got String
```

I hope my Problem is understandable.

Update:
After the hint from Gopal Vashishtha i changed the input/output names:

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(outputColumnName: "image_object", imageFolder: imgFolder, inputColumnName: inName)
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "image_object_resized", imageWidth: 299, imageHeight: 299, inputColumnName: "image_object"))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "input", inputColumnName: "image_object_resized", interleavePixelColors: true, offsetImage: 117, scaleImage: 1 / 255f))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(outputColumnName: outName, inputColumnName: "input", modelFile: pathToMLFile + "\\Converted.onnx", fallbackToCpu: true))
```

But i still have the same Error. Might there be a Problem with the way i trained the Model? I used a numpy-array as image and 0/1/2 for the corresponding Classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [samples](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/3c38284ed183a1d56fda86c300a7774964e19988/samples/csharp/getting-started/DeepLearning_TensorFlowEstimator/ImageClassification.Train/Model/ModelBuilder.cs#L65), you can see that the output column in a chain of transforms needs to match the input column of the next estimator. I notice that in your example, you use the same input and output column name throughout.